# Another ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ListView

Tags: android

This one is different than the other one I posted.  Any ideas?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
Invalid location 14, size is 1
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
       at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:188)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1256)
       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:667)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:613)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2531)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2353)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method)
```

Comment: Do you have more than one Thread that could modify your data size at the same time?

Comment: No, anything that other threads do only modify the data/gui on the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, your `ListView` thinks that either there are 14+ headers or 14+ footers, but there is only one.

Why it thinks that is impossible to say given only a stack trace. It is somewhat more likely that the problem is with the footers, and that the real problem is somewhere in the adapter you are using on the `ListView`, perhaps dynamically changing the number of rows improperly.